# Server calls hang forever, only on android *built* app

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

My app works perfectly:

- On browser, both locally and deployed
- On emulator, using either the local or deployed server
- On my device when using `run android-device`, using either the local or deployed server

But somehow, when I build it following [these instructions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-submit-your-Android-app-to-Play-Store), at the first server call, for example:

```
console.log("test1");
Meteor.call("someMethod", function (error, result) {
  console.log("test2");
});
// yes I know how asynchronous calls work
console.log("test3");
```

Or:

```
console.log("test1");
Meteor.loginWithPassword("validUsername", "validPassword", function (error, result) {
  // should print no matter if the credentials are good or bad anyway
  console.log("test2");
});
console.log("test3");
```

"test2" does not get printed in the adb logcat, even though "test1" and "test3" do. There is a mapbox map that loads fine, so it's not an internet access issue. Also, startup works:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  console.log("this gets printed in the adb console");
});
```

So it's not ALL Meteor methods. I used both my deployed and local server: there were no errors reported on the server log. I also tested hot-code push on my local server, it does reload the app on my phone! But only the first time I launch the app only after it's freshly installed. Still, there is at least some kind of connection between them.

I should also mention that I already built this app and it worked fine before, but I did not build it in a while and now it doesn't work anymore. I installed the package on two different devices and get the exact same issue.

Here is my package list if it can help, all on the latest version available:

```
meteor-platform
iron:router
sacha:spin
accounts-password
accounts-base
mdg:geolocation
mrt:flash-messages
mdg:camera
useraccounts:ratchet
fastclick
alanning:roles
tap:i18n
simple:imgur
```

Here are the client's logs when I launch it on my local server:

```
I/CordovaLog(18991): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
I/CordovaLog(18991): Found start page location: index.html
D/CordovaLog(18991): file:///android_asset/www/meteor_cordova_loader.js: Line 12 : METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Error reading version file Error: Failed to resolve entry: file:///data/data/com.idz9099616fhad1150nrz/files/meteor/version
D/CordovaLog(18991): file:///android_asset/www/meteor_cordova_loader.js: Line 12 : METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Couldn't load from the manifest, falling back to the bundled assets.
D/CordovaLog(18991): file:///android_asset/www/meteor_cordova_loader.js: Line 12 : METEOR CORDOVA DEBUG (meteor_cordova_loader.js) Loading from url: http://meteor.local
D/CordovaLog(18991): http://meteor.local/d7372e9a56ce9d5ddfb0fea0d5e071cfd699fac8.js: Line 111 : show showSignInLink signIn
```

These are all before I hit "Sign In" on my app. That last statement is just a log print from the `useraccounts:ratchet` package that occurs everywhere. As soon as I hit "Sign in": blank page, and zero output on the logs. (that's due to the fact that I can never actually stop logging in, as we saw earlier) The above log remains as it is forever.

When using the app installed with `run android-device`, it's the same exact output, except that after I click, the next page shows up and everything works fine. (logging works, as everything else) As with the non-functionning app, no more log lines show up. (except when I start using the app as usual)

What really bugs me is that it works perfectly fine on my phone when I install the app using `run android-device`. Even when I stop the debug and use this build as a standalone app, it works flawlessly! But I cannot decently ask users to install my app using `meteor run`, can I?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail on what you mean by the first server interaction & login and what you disabled. Also if you're building both (local and production) on the same device make sure you completely uninstall either before running them or the local-data html files will be the wrong ones.

Comment: Sure thing, will edit in a minute. And yes I forgot to mention it, but I did erase data and uninstall the app on my phone before each test.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, [the issue on github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3698) is going strong.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've provided it looks like you have a race condition issue in your code. I'm not assured this is what it is, but the characteristic of the problem you're describing makes it quite likely.

On your local server it doesn't pop up because the connection is fairly instantaneous, but on a remote server it's more of an issue since the data may not yet be ready due to the higher latency.

Basically you have something *like* this in your code, or a variation in some way:

```
var doc = MyCollection.findOne();
return doc.name
```

The thing is `MyCollection.findOne()` is `null` (since the data has not yet loaded). This calls up a `cannot read 'name' of undefined` error (client side not server side) and this halts the execution of further code, which is why your screen is white and the subscriptions aren't run.

How to find where this is exactly. Try and get access to `adb` to view the client side logs on the device or view and login with `xxx.meteor.com`/your deployed server on your web browser and keep an eye on the JS console to find where it pops up. *The key thing to reproduce the issue is a slower connection to the server than that available on your localhost*

The fix is simply accounting for a lack of data, i.e `return doc && doc.name` instead of `return doc.name` or `if(doc != null) return doc.name;`

Comment: And this issue would not occur on a `run android-device` version of the app? Because if I install the app using `run android-device` I can end the debug and use it perfectly fine, it is basically a standalone android app. That is the thing that really annoys me.

Comment: @BraveKenny yes it would be fine as long as its using a local low latency server. If there's not enough time for the data to be retrieved thats when the problem occurs

Comment: When I build it using `run android-device --server https://myproductionserver.com:443` it all works fine. Not when I build it using `build ../output --server https://myproductionserver.com:443`. But it's the same "high latency" server :(

Comment: @BraveKenny Could you check up the client side logs via adb? or pass along the productionserver.com so I could look for the issue

Comment: Thanks for your help. I put the logs from the client

Comment: Also, now that I know how to use the adb logcat, I re-wrote the actual problem ;)